# Problem with passing data to other component in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-props

Hey  guys I have a Problem I need to redirect the User to a chat component which opens a chat forr the user if he clicks on it.

[image]

so in the Image you can see the Profil Steve Jobs and I want to create a Button which directs the User to my chat component to the specific chat. But my problem is if I try this with props the chat interface spawns in the `Search Page`

[image]

As you can see this is not what I want the `Chat Button` should direct me to the chat component with an open Chat like in the second picture.

Heres the Code from my Chat Component if you need also from the Search Component let me know. The prop `waffen` is the Data Array of the User which contains its `Uid` as well as some other Attributes like `Name` or his `Profile Picture`.

```
const SucheChat = ({waffen}) => {

  const classes = useStyles();
  
  const [chat, setChat] = useState("");
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [img, setImg] = useState("");
  const [msgs, setMsgs] = useState([]);

  const user1 = auth.currentUser.uid;
  const user2 = chat.uid;

 

  const selectUser = async (waffen) => {
    setChat(waffen);

    const user2 = waffen.uid;
    const id = user1 > user2 ? `${user1 + user2}` : `${user2 + user1}`;

    const msgsRef = collection(db, "messages", id, "chat");
    const q = query(msgsRef, orderBy("createdAt", "asc"));

    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      let msgs = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        msgs.push(doc.data());
      });
      setMsgs(msgs);
    });

    // get last message b/w logged in user and selected user
    const docSnap = await getDoc(doc(db, "lastMsg", id));
    // if last message exists and message is from selected user
    if (docSnap.data() && docSnap.data().from !== user1) {
      // update last message doc, set unread to false
      await updateDoc(doc(db, "lastMsg", id), { unread: false });
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user2 = chat.uid;

    const id = user1 > user2 ? `${user1 + user2}` : `${user2 + user1}`;

    let url;
    if (img) {
      const imgRef = ref(
        storage,
        `images/${new Date().getTime()} - ${img.name}`
      );
      const snap = await uploadBytes(imgRef, img);
      const dlUrl = await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, snap.ref.fullPath));
      url = dlUrl;
    }

    await addDoc(collection(db, "messages", id, "chat"), {
      text,
      from: user1,
      to: user2,
      createdAt: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
      media: url || "",
    });

    await setDoc(doc(db, "lastMsg", id), {
      text,
      from: user1,
      to: user2,
      createdAt: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
      media: url || "",
      unread: true,
    });

    setText("");
    setImg("");
  };
```

And here what I return

```
return (

    <ThemeProvider sx={{mx: "auto"}}  theme={theme}>
    <Box>
        {chat ? (
          <div>
           <Box sx={{overflowY:'scroll',height:{lg:'65vh',md:'87vh',sm:'87vh', xs:'87vh' } ,}}>
            
              {msgs.length
                ? msgs.map((msg, i) => (
                    <Message key={i} msg={msg} user1={user1}  />
                  ))
                  
                : null}
                
           </Box>
            
            <MessageForm
              handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
              text={text}
              setText={setText}
              setImg={setImg}
            />
            
            </div>
        ) : (

          <Grid container spacing={1} alignItems='center' justifyContent='center'>

          <Grid item  >
          
          <Button   onClick={() => selectUser(waffen)} color='secondary' >Start Chat</Button>
           
           </Grid>
         </Grid>
        )}
      
    </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default SucheChat;
```